# Sharing values through namespaces

Tags: c++, string, namespaces

My question is probably stupid, but I can't share a value through namespaces.

```
namespace AceEngine
{
    namespace Graphics
    {
        namespace Interface
        {
            void drawDebugScreen()
            {
                // I want to access AceEngine::System::Version from here.
            }
        }
    }

    namespace System
    {
        string Version("DEBUG");
    }
}
```

How can I access this string?

EDIT:

ae.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "sha256.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::getline;
using std::string;

namespace AceEngine
{
    namespace Graphics
    {
        namespace Interface
        {
            void drawDebugScreen()
            {
                cout << "Version: " << AceEngine::System::Version << endl;
            }
            class Window{};
        }
    }
    namespace System
    {
        class User{};
        void pause(){cin.get();}
        extern string Version("DEBUG");
    }
}
```

ae.h

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
using std::string;

namespace AceEngine
{
    namespace Graphics
    {
        namespace Interface
        {
            void drawDebugScreen();
            class Window{};
        }
    }

    namespace System
    {
        class User{};
        void pause();
        extern string Version;
    }
}
```

I removed the useless parts (I left some classes to show there are stuff in the namespaces and it's not useless)

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1):

As always, names need to be declared before use.

You probably want to declare it in a header, so it can be used from any source file. You need `extern` when declaring a global variable:

```
namespace AceEngine {
    namespace System {
        extern string Version;
    }
}
```

Or, if you only need it in this file, you could just move the `System` namespace to come before whatever needs it.

UPDATE: Now you've posted the full code, the problem is that the source file doesn't include the header.

Comment: I already have a header file; and the string is already declared. I tried to access "extern string Version" using "AceEngine::System::Version" but It's not declared for the compiler.

Comment: @K-WARE: In that case, please update the question to show what you tried and how it didn't work. In the code you posted, the only problem is that it isn't declared at that point. If the compiler says it isn't declared, then it almost certainly isn't.

Comment: @K-WARE: You have a header, but you don't include it; so the string isn't declared.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to place the declaration of the string before its point of use.

```
#include <iostream>   //  for std::cout

namespace AceEngine
{
    namespace System
    {
        string Version("DEBUG");    // declare it here
    }

    namespace Graphics
    {
        namespace Interface
        {
            void drawDebugScreen()   // access it in here
            {
                std::cout << AceEngine::System::Version << '\n;
            }
        }
    }

}

int main()
{
     AceEngine::Graphics::Interface::drawDebugScreen();
     return 0;
}
```

If you need that number of nested namespaces, you're probably over thinking your design.   But that's another story.